# Write system call writes data to disk directly?

Tags: c, io, filesystems, operating-system

I've read couple of questions([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450551/buffered-i-o-vs-unbuffered-io)) related to this but I still have some confusion.

My understanding is that write system call puts the data into `Buffered Cache`(OS caches as referred in that question). When the `Buffered Cache` gets full it is written to the disk.

Buffered IO is further optimization on top of this. It caches in the `C RTL buffers` and when they get full a `write` system call issued to move the contents to `Buffered Cache`. If I use `fflush` then data related to this particular file that is present in the `C RTL buffers` as well as `Buffered Cache` is sent to the disk.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Depends on the OS, the file open mode, system-specific per-file-handle settings...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How the stdio buffers are flushed is depending on the standard C library you use. To quote from the [Linux manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush):

> Note that fflush() only flushes the user space buffers provided by the C library.
>   To ensure that the data is physically stored on disk the kernel buffers must be
>   flushed too, for example, with sync(2) or fsync(2).

This means that on a Linux system, using `fflush` or overflowing the buffer will call the `write` function. But the operating system may keep internal buffers, and not actually write the data to the device. To make sure the data is truly written to the device, use both `fflush` and the low-level `fsync`.

**Edit:** Answer rephrased.

Comment: @JP: I mixed them in the sense that printf finally results in write system call

Comment: @Lamia: I rephrased my answer.