# When does write system call return?

Tags: c

If I'm writing to a file/device in blocking mode does the `write()` call return on writing all the bytes(assume no signal interruption) to `Buffered Cache(Kernel Buffer)` or it returns on writing all bytes to the file/device? (This is extension to my earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416946/write-system-call-writes-data-to-disk-directly)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If successful, `write` returns after writing the data to kernel memory.  The `write` system call makes no guarantees about writing to the disk, you need `fsync` for that.  Actually, `fsync` does not guarantee that the bits were actually written to the platter itself: just that the IO operation is complete.

(Of course, there are various platform-specific modes and settings you can use to alter this behavior.)