# Problem writing a file, the file doesn’t get written until I close the program - Tkinter Python 3 - example code

Tags: python, tkinter

EDIT:
Yes, I have a similar problem as the link below but I don’t think this is a duplicate question because unfortunately, the answer doesn’t solve my problem. [How come a file doesn't get written until I stop the program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824806/how-come-a-file-doesnt-get-written-until-i-stop-the-program)

I tried the `f=open(file,w)` `f.close()` `f.flush()` `os.fsync(f)` and it didn’t help. Please also note that I am using `with` statement that should accomplish the same thing as once the Python exits from the `with` block, the file is automatically closed.

Even all that the file still doesn’t get written until I close the program.

I also noticed now that this is not a Tkinter problem as I thought first, the problem exist without the Tkinter GUI. Might be something to do with the `lxml.etree`

ORIGINAL QUESTION BELOW

I have tried to make a simple GUI for the XML converter script.

I am having problems when saving the file. The file doesn’t get written until I close or destroy() the Tkinter program. Can anyone explain why that would happen and how to fix it? I would like to write the file while the Tkinter window is running.

Please find below the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import lxml.etree as ET
import tkinter.filedialog as fdialog

def mfileopen():
    global xml_file
    xml_file = fdialog.askopenfile()
    Label(text=xml_file) .pack()

def dropdown_select(selection):
    global xslt_file
    if selection == "Stylesheet 1":
        xslt_file = "stylesheet1.xsl"

    elif selection == "Stylesheet 2":
        xslt_file = "stylesheet2.xsl"

def convert_xml(xslt_file, input_xml):
    dom = ET.parse(input_xml)
    xslt = ET.parse(xslt_file)
    transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
    newdom = transform(dom)
    write_file(newdom)

def write_file(csv_file):
    with open("output.csv", "w") as f:
        f.write(str(csv_file))

OPTIONS = [
"Stylesheet 1",
"Stylesheet 2",
]

master = Tk()

Label (text="Open XML file and then Choose XSLT Code from the dorpdown menu and press Load XSLT. Finally press Convert XML") .pack()

button = Button(text="Open XML File", width=30, command=mfileopen)
button.pack()

variable = StringVar(master)
variable.set(OPTIONS[0]) # default value

w = OptionMenu(master, variable, *OPTIONS)
w.pack()

button = Button(master, text="Load XSLT", command=lambda: dropdown_select(variable.get()))
button.pack()

button = Button(master, text="Convert XML", command=lambda: convert_xml(xslt_file, xml_file))
button.pack()

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here.  This code has plenty of superfluous lines.

Comment: Also be careful with globals. Its possible `xslt_file` and `xml_file` don't exist when `convert_xml(xslt_file, xml_file)` is called.

Comment: In the meantime, try tracing the execution: insert a parallel `print` statement to dump the lines as you write to the file.  My suspicion is that you simply haven't filled up the buffer.  Try a `flush` on the output stream as you write.

Comment: @Prune Thank you for your suggestion. `Print` works fine, prints everything as it should, I tried the f.flush() and unfortunately, it didn’t help. Please also note that I am using `with` statement that should accomplish the same thing as once the Python exits from the `with` block, the file is automatically closed.

Comment: @Error - Syntactical Remorse Thank you for pointing out the globals but that's not the problem in this case.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble everyone, I found out the issue. There was actually nothing wrong with the original script, it actually works as it should, even without the flush(). I am using macOS PyCharm and the issue was the PyCharm project folder refresh. The actual file gets written to the disk immediately but as I was looking the PyCharm project folder window that didn’t update until you actually click somewhere in the PyCharm window or when the program stops. Should I just delete this question as it’s actually misleading or edit the question?

Answer (score 1):

You need to `f.close()` to flush the file write buffer out to the file. Or in your case you might just want to do a `f.flush(); os.fsync();` so you can keep looping with the opened file handle.

Don't forget to `import os`.

For more information: [How come a file doesn't get written until I stop the program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824806/how-come-a-file-doesnt-get-written-until-i-stop-the-program)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried the `f=open(file,w)` `f.close()` `f.flush()` `os.fsync(f)` and unfortuantelly it didn’t help.

Comment: @Tim Add the `f.flush()` RIGHT after you write to it. (Inside the `open` statement. Also you don't need a `f.close()` because you have the `with` statement.