# Typing effect in GraphWin

Tags: python, text, iterable

I'm trying to create a text typing effect in a window, however it comes up as 
"TypeError: 'Text' object is not iterable". Here's my current code:

```
from graphics import *
import sys
from time import sleep

window = GraphWin('Test', 1000, 700)

text = Text(Point(500, 150), "This is just a test :P")
words = ("This is just a test :P")
for char in text:
    sleep(0.1)
    sys.stdout.write(char)
    sys.stdout.flush()
word.draw(window)
```

[Source for typing effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20302331/typing-effect-in-python)

The text comes up in the shell if I use the 'words' variable, however becomes a TypeError if I try using the text variable. Is there a way of making it iterable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are getting mixed up and confusing your variables `text` and `words`; second, your `Text` object is not iterable, but you can create several ones to be displayed in succession while iterating over `words'

```
from graphics import *
import sys
from time import sleep

window = GraphWin('Test', 1000, 700)

text = Text(Point(500, 150), "This is just a test :P")
words = "This is just a test :P"

# this prints to console
for char in words:
    sleep(0.1)
    sys.stdout.write(char)
    sys.stdout.flush()

# that displays on canvas
for idx, t in enumerate(words):
    text = Text(Point(300+idx*20, 150), t)
    text.draw(window)
    sleep(0.1)
```

In **python 3**, you can replace the calls to `sys.stdout` with standard `print` calls:

```
# this prints to console
for char in words:
    sleep(0.1)
    print(char, end='', flush=True)
```