# How to have typing effect in Python with inputs/answers?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new with very little experience programming in Python, correct me if my terminology is incorrect.

I've seen posts asking about the [typing effect in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20302331/typing-effect-in-python). But I would also want to use that effect in scripts that require you to answer or type something, like those Choose-Your-Own-Adventure games. For example:

```
answer = input("You reach a crossroad, would you like to go left or right?").lower().strip()
if answer == 'left':
     answer = input('You encounter a monster, would you like to run or attack?')
elif answer == 'right':
     answer = input('You walk aimlessly to the right and fall on a patch of ice.')
```

How would I have something like this have a typing effect?

Comment: Do you mean that the user's input will have the effect (while the user types), or the prompt? If it's the latter, why didn't the link answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function for a typing effect, something like this:

```
import sys
import time

def type_effect(string, delay):
    for char in string:
        time.sleep(delay)
        sys.stderr.write(char)
```

And then use it every time you want to use the effect :)

```
type_effect('You reach a crossroad, would you like to go left or right?', 0.1)
answer = input().lower().strip()
if answer == 'left':
    type_effect('You encounter a monster, would you like to run or attack?', 0.1)
    answer = input()
elif answer == 'right':
    type_effect('You walk aimlessly to the right and fall on a patch of ice.', 0.1)
    answer = input()
```

Or, you can even define a function that uses the type effect and also returns the user's input, like this:

```
import sys
import time

def type_effect_and_input(string, speed):
    for char in string:
        time.sleep(speed)
        sys.stderr.write(char)
    return input().lower().strip()

answer = type_effect_and_input('You reach a crossroad, would you like to go left or right?', 0.1)
if answer == 'left':
    answer = type_effect_and_input('You encounter a monster, would you like to run or attack?', 0.1)
elif answer == 'right':
    answer = type_effect_and_input('You walk aimlessly to the right and fall on a patch of ice.', 0.1)
```

Comment: I need some more info. How can I use it every time I want to use the effect? How would I use it in the context of the example I put in my post?

Comment: Oh I see now, you want to get input and use a typing effect at the same time! OK, updated the answer to include two ways of achieving this :) @wowsocool

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it. I am gonna include in a module called textutils
from time import sleep

```
def slow_print(text, waitTime=0.05):
    for x in text:
        print(x, end='')
        sleep(waitTime)

slow_print("You reach a crossroad, would you like to go left or
right?")
answer = input("").lower().strip()
if answer == 'left':
     slow_print('You encounter a monster, would you like to run or attack?')
     answer = input('')
elif answer == 'right':
     slow_print('You walk aimlessly to the right and fall on a patch of ice.')
     answer = input()
```

Comment: How is this answer different from the other one? It seems to be a duplicate...