# In python for loop time.sleep is not working as i expected

Tags: python, for-loop, time, printing

```
import time as t
def main():
    a = "hello word"
    for i in a:
        t.sleep(0.1)
        print(i,end=" ")
       
main()
```

prints each word without stopping the code

Comment: This may help you. [How do I make a time delay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510348/how-do-i-make-a-time-delay)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typing effect in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20302331/typing-effect-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

use flush:

```
print(i, end=" ", flush=True)
```