# Overwrite the previous print value in python?

Tags: python

How can i overwrite the previous "print" value in python?

```
print "hello"
print "dude"
print "bye"
```

It will output:

```
hello
dude
bye
```

But i want to overwrite the value.

In this case the output will be:

```
bye
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this [curses library](http://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/curses.html#what-is-curses), The curses library supplies a terminal-independent screen-painting and keyboard-handling facility for text-based terminals. An example:

**x.py:**

```
from curses import wrapper
def main(stdscr):
    stdscr.addstr(1, 0, 'Program is running..')  
    # Clear screen
    stdscr.clear()  # clear above line. 
    stdscr.addstr(1, 0, 'hello')
    stdscr.addstr(2, 0, 'dude')
    stdscr.addstr(3, 0, 'Press Key to exit: ')
    stdscr.refresh()
    stdscr.getkey()

wrapper(main)
print('bye')
```

run it  `python x.py`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sys.stdout.write` to avoid the newline printed by `print` at each call and the carriage return `\r` to go back to the beginning of the line:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write("hello")
sys.stdout.write("\rdude")
sys.stdout.write("\rbye")
```

To overwrite all the characters of the previous sentence, you may have to add some spaces.

On python 3 or python 2 with `print` as a function, you can use the `end` parameter:

```
from __future__ import print_function #Only python 2.X
print("hello", end="")
print("\rdude ", end="")
print("\rbye  ", end="")
```

Note that it won't work in IDLE.

Answer (score 2):

```
import os
print "hello"
print "dude"
if <your condition to bye print >
    os.system('clear')
    print "bye"
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to

```
os.system('clear')
```

you can also use

```
print "\n" * 100
```

The value `100` can be changed to what you require

Answer (score 2):

In  `Python 3`:

```
print("hello", end='\r', flush=True)
print("dude", end='\r', flush=True)
print("bye", end='\r', flush=True)
```

Output:

```
bye
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way is.

Write

```
   sys.stdout.flush()
```

After print.

Example:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write("hello")
sys.stdout.flush()
sys.stdout.write("bye")
```

Output: bye

Comment: What doesn't `flush()` do I sounds like `fflush(stdout)` in C. No?

Comment: fflush(stdout) is for c language..
in python flush()

Comment: But fflush doesn't clrear screen

Comment: your answer is not correct it doesn't clears screen. Did you try? Read [Usage of `sys.stdout.flush()` method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10019605/1673391)