# print without new line only appear after I write something else

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm using Python 2.7.3 and I running the code below

```
def t2():
    print "Waiting...",
    time.sleep(3)
    print "done."
    time.sleep(1)
    print "test"
    time.sleep(2)
    print "testing"
```

When I run this code, the string "Waiting... done." appear at same time. It's like the sleep(2) is before the first print.

If I don't use comma to remove new line (Like "test" and "testing" examples), sleep function works ok but I get "Waiting..." and "done." on different lines.

I already tried:

```
for i in range(0, 5): time.sleep(1)
```

and

```
subprocess.check_output(["sleep", "5"])
```

What can I do?

Thank you.

Comment: that's pretty standard for many environments - they don't actually display a buffered string until a newline is added to the buffer. Add a flush() (or whatever python's equivalent is) before each sleep call.

Comment: Try calling `sys.stdout.flush()`. Don't forget to `import sys`

Comment: Interesting. For me, it works just fine. Which platform do you use (Win7/8, OSX, Linux Distro)?

Comment: I'm using Raspbian on Raspberry Pi @DaveJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending what you are working with data doesn't necessarily get written right away. In particular, 
display output often waits until it receives a newline before printing anything.

flush() makes sure it all gets written **right now**.

Background reading that helps explain better than I can:
[Usage of sys.stdout.flush() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019456/usage-of-sys-stdout-flush-method)