# Wait animation "..." to appear over and over

Tags: python, wait

I'm trying to display a sort of loading animation, specifically three dots appearing over and over. I thought the below would work:

```
import time, sys

for i in range(9):
    time.sleep(0.2)
    x = i % 4
    sys.stdout.write("." * x)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

However all it does is just gradually (and non-uniformly) load this: `"........."`

Comment: I don't think `sys.stdout.flush` does what you think; see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/10019456/3001761

Comment: Try `sys.stdout.write('\r' + "." * x)` instead

Comment: 'sys.stdout.write('\r' + "." * x)' worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `\r` the return character. This is because your cursor should return to the original position after you lapse the time

```
import time, sys

for i in range(15):
    sys.stdout.write("   ")
    x = i % 4
    sys.stdout.write('\r' + "." * x )
    time.sleep(0.5)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```