# python : redirect output to text file and display it in real time

Tags: jquery, python, real-time, logfile

I have a python function that calls many services, and prints results of the services called in a log file. this is my code :

```
def coordinator():
   f = file(path,'a')
   sys.stdout = f
   /* do a lot of stuff */
   f.close()
   with open(path) as log:
        logs = log.read()
        return jsonify(log = logs)
```

The result of the function is returned to a jQuery getJSON function that displays the final log file in a web page :

```
$.getJSON('/../coordinator',
  {//parameters},
  function(data) {
    //display data.log
  }
);
```

My problem is that the user gets to see the log file only when the execution is finished. 
Is there a way to display logs as they are written in real time??

Comment: `coordinator` could start the operation in the background and return immediately with some sort of identifier for the log file. Another method could be written to read the file. There are lots of other options including highly deluxe middleware that uses something like `zeromq` to start operations and provide a publisher to track how operations are going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what I was looking for here :

http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-websockets-with-flask-and-gevent

So basically I created a WebSocket between the Back-end (Python/Flask) and the Front-end (HTML, jquery) to ensure continuous communication.

And with Python I created a Thread that runs asynchronously with the Master thread, fetches repetitively the content of the log file and sends them to Jquery via ajax

Answer (score 1):

Python's `stdout` is buffered, so it won't write until the buffer is full. To force an immediate write, use [`sys.stdout.flush()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10019605/1426065), or `f.flush()` in the case of your code.

Comment: I already did that but I couldn't figure out how to fetch the file after f.flush()

Comment: Python's `stdout` buffering is determined by whether its attached to a `pty`. OP replaces `stdout` with an open file and its the open file, not the original `stdout` that's buffered. That said, where is OP supposed to put the flushes?

Comment: I put the flushes in the services that are called by the coordinator function, but after that I didn't know how to fetch the file repetitively