# python : print the multiple lines on console in place

Tags: python, printing

I want to print multiple lines on console in place. 
Like this,

```
AAAAAA

BBBBBB
```

But, If I print above the strings using `'\r'` as below,

```
for i in range(10):
   time.sleep(1)
   print("AAAA\r", end='')
   time.sleep(1)
   print("BBBB\r", end='')
```

The final result is just like this

```
 BBBB
```

What's happening is `AAAA`->`BBBB`->`AAAA`->`BBBB`..... and it's not printing like this(IN PLACE!):

```
AAAA

BBBB
```

Not Like this

```
AAAA

BBBB

AAAA

BBBB

AAAA

BBBB

...
```

Is there any solution about this? Please help me

Comment: So you only want to show `BBBB`?

Comment: `end=''` why this?

Comment: Is this all your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Usage of sys.stdout.flush() method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019456/usage-of-sys-stdout-flush-method)

Comment: You want to show AAAA one second, then BBBB (printed over AAAA) another second and so, ten times? If you use AA and BBBB, at some time, you will have AABB... Its is OK? In my machine, using Python 3.5.1 :: Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit), that is the behavior obtained.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want ..

```
for i in range(10):
    time.sleep(1)
    print("AAAAA\n\n")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("BBBBB\n\n")
```