# How to print multiples lines at a same place in Python 3 console

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is ofcourse a duplicate question but I still did not get any answer...

Here the duplicate question [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38690083/python-print-the-multiple-lines-on-console-in-place)

```
import time

print("The progress is going on as below...")

for i in range(1,6):
    print("\r" + "Done - " + str(i))
    print("\r" + "Left - " + str(5 - i))
    time.sleep(2)
```

I want to get the output as :

Done - 1
Left - 4

and again overwriting the 1 and 4 I want...

Done - 2
Left - 3

and again by over writing...

Done - 3
Left - 2

and so on.... I want all this to be overwritten.. in the 2 lines everytime while loops executes...

**I want partial screen cleaning only those 2 lines... Not complete screen cleaning nor running multiple blank lines... Hope I am clear.
Anyway possible ?**

Kindly someone help...

This question is duplicate I accept but I could not find the solution for it... Please don't mark it down I just need help...

Please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Rewrite multiple lines in the Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840420/python-rewrite-multiple-lines-in-the-console)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text Progress Bar in the Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173320/text-progress-bar-in-the-console)

Answer (score 2):

This is the library you're looking for:
https://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html

```
import curses, time
stdscr = curses.initscr()
for i in range(0, 5):
    stdscr.addstr(0, 0, '{0}'.format(i))
    stdscr.refresh()
    time.sleep(1)
curses.endwin()
```

Give something like this a try, it'll print numbers 0-4 in the upper left corner of your terminal.

EDIT:

here's the exact code you're looking for

```
import curses, time

stdscr = curses.initscr()
for i in range(1,6):
    stdscr.addstr(0, 0, "Done - " + str(i))
    stdscr.addstr(1, 0, "Left - " + str(5 - i))
    stdscr.refresh()
    time.sleep(2)

curses.endwin()
```

Comment: Will give it a try sir and let you know if its working or not ^_^

Comment: I just read your question again, is there other text on the screen? This solution doesn't clear the screen but it does put the lines in an absolute position. If you need something more dynamic that can be achieved with the same library but will take a little more work.

Comment: Also, curses only updates sections of the screen that have changed, so you might get some "after images" if you add strings of varying size on top of one another.

Answer (score 1):

```
from curses import wrapper
import time

def main(stdscr):
   # Clear screen
   stdscr.clear()

   for i in range(0, 5):
      print("Done - %d" % i)
      print("Left - %d" % (5 - i))
      time.sleep(2)
      stdscr.clear()
      stdscr.refresh()
   print('press any key ...')
   stdscr.getkey()

wrapper(main)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this solves your problem. Let me know if you have any doubts.

```
import time
import os
clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
clear()
for i in range(1,6):
    print("\r" + "Done - " + str(i))
    print("\r" + "Left - " + str(5 - i))
    time.sleep(2)
    if i!=5:
        clear()
    else:
        exit()
```

Comment: No brother I thought of this too but... I already have some printed statements in the window so I can't completely clear the screen... :(

Comment: Okay. Partial screen cleaning. You should mention that in the description.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not working for you is `print()` automatically adds a newline `\n` to each line. Add `end=''` to the print call to override that.

`print("\r" + "Done - " + str(i), end='')`

Comment: I see from other answers you're on Windows. This answer works on Linux (or any POSIX-based environment)

Answer (score 0):

After you print, the text is pretty much permanent. Only way you could "change" what it says is to reprint. just run this code before reprinting and it should clear the screen.

```
print "\n" * 100
```

Though you could put this in a function:

```
def cls(): print "\n" * 100
```

And then call it when needed as cls()

Comment: Sorry I know these kind of ideas but that is not I want thanks though ^_^

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick, but it only works with 1 line. for multiple lines you will have to use one of the other solutions like clear output screen.

```
import time

for i in range(1,6):
    print("\r" + "Done - " + str(i) + " pending - " + str(5 - i), end='')
    time.sleep(2)
```

Final output:

```
Done - 5 pending - 0
```

Comment: I want in different line only bro... anyway thanks for responding ^_^

Comment: @Karan solutions to clear multiple lines will be jugads, I would suggest you go with 1 line output clearing.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `sys.stdout.write` and `sys.stdout.flush` to achieve this. Here  `"\033[F"` moves the cursor up one line (which is an [ANSI Escape Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)). It **works on POSIX based machines**. *(PS: It won't work on older versions windows as windows and DOS as they were not supporting ANSI)*

```
import sys

for i in range(1,6):
    sys.stdout.write("\033[FDone - " + str(i))
    sys.stdout.write("\nLeft - " + str(5 - i))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(2)
```

Sample Run:

```
Done - 1
Left - 4

# after 2 seconds (last two lines replaced with)
Done - 2
Left - 3

# after 2 more seconds (last two lines replaced with)
Done - 3
Left - 2

# after 2 more seconds (last two lines replaced with)
Done - 4
Left - 1

# after 2 more seconds (last two lines replaced with)
Done - 5
Left - 0
```

Comment: @Karan which character are you talking about ? Which Os are you using?

Comment: I am using win 10... wait I will put the screenshot of the output

Comment: Ok. Got it. Windows doesn't support ANSI

Comment: This is the link to image you can view it ... --> https://ibb.co/jdtXNc

Comment: btw where does this support ? like in which OS

Comment: I am using Mac where it works. It should work on other UNIX flavors as well. However I think (not sure) recent windows should also be supporting it but not sure whether windows 10 is supporting it or not.