# The backspace character is not Working - printing on cmd using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, the problem is that i am printing character using python's `print()` functions.

```
print("hello world \b\bs", end='', flush=True)
```

But it doesn't print `hello worls` rather it prints `hello world`.

I think `"\b"` makes the cursor go back one character and delete that one.
Above we have a space between `'d'` of the `'world'` and `'\b\bs'` that's why i used two backspace's.

[Delete last printed character python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42313277/delete-last-printed-character-python)
above ans doesn't work!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete last printed character python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42313277/delete-last-printed-character-python)

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue on Gnome-Terminal on Linux, so I'm guessing this issue is specific to Windows/Windows Console. Does `s` not appear at all in the output? Do you have another console system you could test on, like Windows Terminal, WSL, IDLE, Spyder, and/or Git Bash?

Comment: @wjandrea I don't know how but now it is working.