# Printing same line in python3 with a function callback

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a function that returns a 'pulse' every time it does something. The function must be passed as a callback if the person desires to receive the pulse. I'd like to print the pulses as new `.` character in the same line, so I did this:

```
import time

def do_something(do=None):
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        if do: do('.')

def prtn(text):
    print(text, end=' ')

do_something(prtn)
```

but the code gets stuck and won't print anything!

Comment: you'll probably need to flush the output stream to see the output..

Comment: @thebjorn yes, it worked. But why?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs http://stackoverflow.com/a/10019605/1810460

Comment: @Hamms but why it isn't needed for print() but yes for print(something, end='')

Comment: @Hamms link explains the how, the reason it is done, as for most caching, is for performance. Stdout is line-cached, which is why you might not need a flush when using regular print (this can be os-dependent however).

Comment: Isn't `do` a reserved keyword that can't be used as an identifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print` is line buffered by default, and you are using `print` to print a value not terminated by a new line. So you will need to flush the buffer as a result in order to force it to output the value. See some ways of [how to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print).

Answer (score -1):

**You call a function like a parameter...**

```
import time

def prtn(text):
    print(text, end=' ')

def do_something(do=False):
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        if prtn: prtn('.')

do_something(do=True)
```

Comment: 1. This does not solve OP's problem and 2. you missed the point: OP **wants** to pass a function as a parameter.