# Refactoring a fake loading bar?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a, "fake" loading bar as just a small task. I'm new to coding and this seems to work, but it seems a lot of code. I assume could be done in like 2 lines by someone with more skill than me. I would love to see how this could be refactored into a more efficient way. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
loading_bar = "LOADING\n[==========]"

print(loading_bar[0:10])
time.sleep(.300)
os.system('cls')
print(loading_bar[0:11])
time.sleep(.300)
os.system('cls')
print(loading_bar[0:12])
time.sleep(.300)
os.system('cls')
print(loading_bar[0:13])
time.sleep(.300)
os.system('cls')
print(loading_bar[0:14])
time.sleep(.300)
os.system('cls')
print(loading_bar[0:15])
time.sleep(.300)
os.system('cls')
print(loading_bar[0:16])
time.sleep(.300)
os.system('cls')
print(loading_bar[0:17])
time.sleep(.300)
os.system('cls')
print(loading_bar[0:18])
time.sleep(.300)
os.system('cls')
print(loading_bar)
```

I'm sorry if this isn't in the right place. I'm new to StackOverflow as well.

Comment: Just use a loop for the whole middle part.

Comment: hint: `for i in range(10,19):`

Comment: Besides  the answers, avoid `os.system('cls')` like the plague. It is the code equivalent of having your frontdoor lock broken and calling a locksmith each time you are leaving or arriving home (instead of asking him to fix it) .
(You create an external process just to erase the screen, and it is a system dependent command).

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way-

```
import sys
import time
loading= "LOADING\n"
bar = "[==========]"
print(loading)
for c in bar:
    time.sleep(0.3)
    sys.stdout.write(c)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

**Explanation**: The `for c in bar` loop means "for each character c in the string bar". And before printing each character there's the delay just like in your code. Then I've used `sys.stdout.write` instead of `print` to avoid printing newline. `sys.stdout.flush()` means to immediately print the output onto terminal which otherwise would stay in a buffer. You can imagine buffer to be like a internal variable which to which we can keep on appending using `print` or `sys.stdout.write`. More info on it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019456/usage-of-sys-stdout-flush-method)

If you need help understanding anything else feel free to comment :)

Comment: I like this. I don't understand what, "c," is in this code. And What does flush do? Thanks for helping. :D

Answer (score 1):

There is a neat library for displaying progress in terminal, named `tqdm`. Install it with

```
$ pip install tqdm
```

Example script:

```
import time
from tqdm import tqdm

seconds = 10

for i in tqdm(range(seconds)):
    time.sleep(1)  # sleep one second in each iteration
```

Run the script:

```
$ python spam.py
100%|██████████████████████████████| 10/10 [00:10<00:00,  1.00s/it]
```

`tqdm` is highly customizable, check out the documentation available on its [PyPI page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tqdm). Example with prepending custom message before the progress bar:

```
import time
from tqdm import tqdm

for i in tqdm(range(10), desc='LOADING'):
    time.sleep(1)
```

Output:

```
$ python spam.py
LOADING: 100%|█████████████████████| 10/10 [00:10<00:00,  1.00s/it]
```