# Replication of the Bash tee command behavior in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, tee

I have a collection of Bash scripts which I want to recreate in python. One of the key feature of these scripts is when i execute them 
it will save the contents of the terminal into a logfile. In Bash simply i used the tee command.

```
2>&1 | tee "logfile.txt";
```

the problem is to find equal solution for python.

I found two half of this "puzzle" so far (solution A and B), 
one of the expected behaviour works in one of the scripts but not in the other and vice versa.

solution A)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT


with Popen(['ffmpeg','-i','1.webm','-y','1.mp3'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, bufsize=1) as p, \
    open('logfile.txt', 'ab') as file:
    for line in p.stdout:
        sys.stdout.buffer.write(line)
        file.write(line)
```

solution B)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE


with Popen(['ffmpeg','-i','1.webm','-y','1.mp3'], stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True) as p:
    logfile = open('logfile.txt', 'w')
    for line in p.stdout:
        print(line, end='')
```

i tried to "merge" the features of these 2 code snippets, but i cant figure it out, how to put it together.

What i looking for is the **EXACT** behavior replication of the tee command in a python script file. which means...

- the contents of the terminal appear in the terminal window **AND** saved into a log file (just like solution A)
- when i start the python script file, i want to follow the progress of the process in the terminal, to check how far is from completion (just like solution B). 
  I dont want to stare at a blank screen until the process completes (solution A).

I would appreciate the help.

for testing i use a webm format file (downloaded with youtube-dl) and convert it to mp3 with ffmpeg in cygwin. 
you can download the ffmpeg binary from here if you want experimenting with it https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html

Thank you!

Comment: Could it be just a matter of flushing stdout after each line in solution A? And why use `sys.stdout.buffer.write(line)` in solution A instead of `print` like in solution B?

Comment: I think all you need is indeed `sys.stdout.flush()` inside your inner loop. Relevant (but not duplicate) question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10019605/3216427

Answer (score 1):

I did some testing and no, sys.stdout.flush() doesn't solve it. The problem appears to be within the Popen/PIPE implementation itself -- the way it sets up pipes between the subprocess and your process introduces buffering.

What does seem to fix this is to:

```
$ export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
```

in the environment you run your Python script from. (The variable can be set to anything.)

To solve this within your Python script itself, there may be a more elegant way, but this rather odd approach seemed to work for me. I'm rerunning the script with that environment variable set:

```
import os
from subprocess import run

if not "PYTHONUNBUFFERED" in os.environ:
    os.environ["PYTHONUNBUFFERED"] = "1"
    completed = run(sys.argv)
    sys.exit(completed.returncode)
```

Found some pointers to this solution here in [question 230751](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-print-function).

Answer (score 1):

You are reading line by line, but `ffmpeg` does not output distinct lines.

You should do what `tee` does and read buffer by buffer, ignoring linefeeds:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.8

import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

with Popen(['ffmpeg','-i','1.webm','-y','1.mp3'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, bufsize=0) as p, \
    open('logfile.txt', 'ab') as file:

    while buf := p.stdout.read(4096):
        sys.stdout.buffer.write(buf);
        sys.stdout.buffer.flush()
        file.write(buf)
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to re-open the case, and with some tinkering i was able to come up with the solution, but i thank you all for your efforts!

```
#! /bin/python3

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
 
with Popen(['ffmpeg','-i','test.wav','-y','1.mp3'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, universal_newlines=True) as process, \
    open('logfile.txt', 'w') as logfile:
    for line in process.stdout:
        
        print(line) 
        logfile.write(line)

    logfile.close()
```