# Mantaining a connection between C# and Python using stdout

Tags: python, c#, stdout, stdin

I'm trying to maintain a connection between a C# and a Python script. I want to read the output from python at the same moment it is printed, but I can do it once the python script is finished, not during its execution.

Here is the C# program, which read asynchronously the stdout stream.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace PruebaConnexion
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
            start.FileName = "D:\\Programas\\Anaconda\\python.exe";
            start.Arguments = ".\\PythonScript.py";
            start.UseShellExecute = false;
            start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            // start.RedirectStandardInput = true;

            Process process = Process.Start(start);
            process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hello "+e.Data);
            });

            process.BeginOutputReadLine();

            while (true)
            {}
            
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the python code:

```
import time
import sys

for i in range(10):
    time.sleep(1)

    sys.stdout.write("OK")
```

I also tried with `print`, instead of `sys.stdout.write`. I get printed on C#:

```
Hello OKOKOKOKOKOKOKOKOKOK
```

But what I need is:

```
Hello OK
Hello OK
Hello OK
.
.
```

One `Hello OK` per second, but not all of them at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

> I also tried with print, instead of sys.stdout.write. I get printed on C#:

I tested with `sys.stdout.write` and got same result, but it worked as expected with `print`. I am using python3 on WSL. I also got it to work like this:

```
sys.stdout.write("OK\n")
```

So it seems like c# will read the data line by line

Comment: Yes, you get that output but not 1 every second. It prints 10 ```Hello OK``` at the same time.

Comment: [sys.stdout.flush()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019456/usage-of-sys-stdout-flush-method/10019605) might help.

Comment: It worked!! Thank you so much, flush forces python to write on stream.