# Python can't print correctly

Tags: python, tensorflow

recently I'm running a deep learning model using tensorflow 1 and python 3 and I met this bug.

I have some code like this:

```
_, run_lr, loss = sess.run([optimizer, run_lr_op, loss_op], feed_dict=dict(zip(placeholders, train)))
eval_input = sess.run(eval_input_op, feed_dict=dict(zip(placeholders, train)))
batch_eval_inputs.append(eval_input)
    if step % 10 == 0:
        print('\nstep {}: train loss {:.4f} run_lr {:.6f}'.format(step, loss, run_lr))
```

and the print() function doesn't output anything.

I also tried adding some other simple print(), like add a print('hello world') before if. But this doesn't output anything either.

Comment: Are you multiprocessing in windows? It won't print from within a spawned process. Not sure on linux.

Comment: @Amiga500 I had run it on both Linux(GPU) and MacOS(CPU), none of them print correctly :(

Comment: Have you tried using `sys.stdout.flush()`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019456/usage-of-sys-stdout-flush-method

Comment: Were you multiprocessing Repoleved?

Comment: Check the `if` condition or add `else` part to verify the result. Thanks!