Why does this not print hello at the end but instead the letters are all scrambled
Im tying to create a effect that make the string "hello" gradually appear:
import time

text = "hello"
alphebet = [
    "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o",
    "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"
]
rtext = []
charNum = -1
alpheNum = -1
matching = 0
for char in text:
  charNum += 1
  while matching == 0:
    alpheNum += 1
    rtext.append(alphebet[alpheNum])
    print(*rtext)
    if alphebet[alpheNum] == char:
      matching = 1
    else:
      rtext.remove(rtext[charNum])
    time.sleep(0.2)
  alpheNum = -1
  matching = 0


I tried to make it so in each iteration of the for loop for each letter of the text your trying to display they go through each letter and print it as well until it finds the letter and moves on to the next.

Are you looking for "hello" to be printed out eventually over many lines or do you want the word to print out over a single line that gets longer as you go?

I think the main issue you have is that you want to "undo" the append with rtext = rtext[:-1] rather than rtext.remove(rtext[charNum]). Note that will make the charNum unneeded.

Your looping has a lot more state management than you need.
import time
import sys

text = "hello"
alphabet = [
    "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o",
    "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"
]
rtext = []
for char in text:
    for achar in alphabet:
        print(f"\b{achar}",end="")
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.2)
        if char == achar:
            print (" ", end="")
            break
print("\b")


I think you was confused of the effect i was looking for i was looking for more of a kind of repeated effect however this still looks cool could you explain what sys.stdout.flush() does however please I am a beginner

@JakobBrooks It forces the console to write whatever is buffered immediately instead of waiting: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10019456

did I misunderstand?  what did you have in mind?

Try it:
import time

text = "hello"
alphabet = [
    "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", 
"o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"
]
text1 = [i for i in text]

for j in range(len(text)):
    for k in range(26):
        if text1[j] != alphabet[k]:
            print(text[:j] + alphabet[k])
        if text1[j] == alphabet[k]:
            print(text[:j] + alphabet[k])
            break  
        time.sleep(0.2)


I ran your code in 2 diff environments, one in IDE one in python CLI itself and I cannot reproduce what you're seeing ... the output cycles as it should until it spells "hello"

It works. The Time module is built into Python. Did you check your Python installation or other code including the time module?

if I can't reproduce a problem as stated (he said he had a problem not seeing hello output) that means there's no problem as I see it, I ran his code and it ran fine .. hope that's explicit enough :).
