# Sorting a binary file with structs

Tags: c++, sorting, file-io, binary-data

I'm working on a C++ program that deals with Pokémon data stored in a binary file. The program reads Pokémon records from a binary file, sorts them based on their power, and then writes the sorted Pokémons back to another binary file. However, I'm encountering issues with the sorting function.

```
struct Pokemon
{
    char Name[50];

    int Type;

    unsigned Power;
};
```

The sortPokemons function is receiving an input stream which is associated with a binary file containing pokemons (which are NOT sorted) and an output stream which is associated with the file in which we should store the sorted pokemons (by their `Power`).

```
void sortPokemons(std::istream& is, std::ostream& os)
{
    unsigned count = 1;

    while (true)
    {
        Pokemon p = readPokemonFromBinary(is);

        if (is.eof())
        {
            break;
        }

        Pokemon min;
        min.Power = INT32_MAX;

        while (true)
        {
            Pokemon c = readPokemonFromBinary(is);

            if (is.eof())
            {
                break;
            }

            if (c.Power < min.Power)
            {
                min = c;
            }
        }

        printPokemon(min);

        is.clear(); //the eof bit is set for the inner while to end
        is.seekg(count * sizeof(Pokemon), std::ios::beg);
        count++;
        writePokenomToBinary(min, os);
    }
}
```

Note that we know that the input file would contain only sequential pokemon records in it.

The following algorithm won't work and I think I know why: I am trying to simulate the selection sort algorithm, but for it in order to work we need to swap the elements if needed, which I am not sure how to do using only files. Is there a more elegant approach to achieve my goal (a new file containing the pokemons sorted by their `Power` in ascending order)? Is my idea valid?

Comment: Read the entire file to a `vector` and sort it using `std::sort`. Sorting a file without reading the entre file into RAM is an advanced topic, I don't recommend tackling it just now.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI, that's exactly what I am trying to avoid. I don't want to read the entire entry file into an array of pokemons for example and sort the pokemons in it with some sorting algorithm (selection sort). I am trying to achieve all that by just using files (without arrays).

Comment: What you want to do is possible but not simple. It looks like you could benefit from learning a bit more (or a lot more) about sorting before you are ready to tackle it.

Comment: Store all your pokemon in an std::vector<Pokemon> pokemons, create predicate functions for sorting e.g. `bool sort_by_power(const Pokemon& lhs, const Pokemon& rhs) { return lhs.Power < rhs.Power; }`. And then `std::sort(pokemons.begin(), pokemons.end(), sort_by_power);`. Note you probably are better of NOT storing pokemon data in binary format (the content of a binary will vary from compiler to compiler , 32/64 bit builds and possibly compiler settings).

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI, I appreciate your attempt at guidance. However, instead of wasting time on what you think I can't handle, why not focus on giving me some advice on what I need to check up on? I need practical suggestions on what to learn and how to tackle the problem, not empty platitudes. Let's get to the point or just stop the discussion. Thanks!

Comment: @SAQ Binary serialization is the REAL hard problem here. If you want to sort easily use the idomatic C++ approach, store your data in a STL container and use std::sort then write a new file. For serialization use a library like protobuf for binary or nlohman json for json file formats.

Comment: @SAQ I also think n.m.coulebanAI's commments are valid, your code does kind of show you're not that familiar with C++ yet.  (e.g. using char[50] to store strings). INT32_MAX instead of `std::numeric_limits<std::int32_t>::max()` . Mixining responsibilites in your sort functions (sorting and file I/O)

Comment: @PepijnKramer, what do you mean mixing sorting and file I/O? That's the whole idea. I don't want to read the whole file beforehand.

Comment: What you need to learn first is that fact that in real life if your data set is smaller than your RAM, you just use RAM (or otherwise waste your employer's time and get fired). If your goal is to learn how to do external sort, read [this wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting).

Comment: @SAQ -- What is the reason why you want to use files?  If it is *not* because the amount of data exceeds RAM, then there really isn't a justification to resort to external sorting.  If it is because the amount of data is so large that internal sorting becomes an issue, then as mentioned in the comments made, you are looking for an external sort, a topic that has been solved since tape storage devices back in the 60's.  [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20802396/how-external-merge-sort-algorithm-works) as an example.

Comment: @SAQ And yet that is what I recommend you do. Read everything into  an std::vector<Pokemon> sort it and write it to a new output file.  And even if your data is larger than your RAM it will (almost) certainly not be larger than your VRAM. So unless you have a real performance issue... keep it simple. If you don't want to read everything in RAM I think you're better of storing the data in a database and use queries on that.

Comment: Use a vector of positions into the originating file.  Sort the vector of positions based on power of the record at that position.  Write to the new file the data from the source file using the vector of positions to read each record in that order, and write those records out in that sorted order.  It'll be x1000 slower than reading it all in at once, sorting it in memory, and then writing it out.  So 5ms instead of 5µs.

Comment: Why are you sorting the data file?  You should create one or more index files.  The index file contain pairs of `<key, data-record>`.  This file will be easier to sort.  Haul this file into memory and use it for accessing the data file in a sorted manner.  Research "database theory index files".

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. Random access on an input stream. Is that even possible? It's unexpected.

But even with random access on your file type, your algorithm is flawed. The first time through the loop, you will read the entire input file and find the lowest power one, then write it out. Great. You're good so far.

The second time through your outer loop, you'll skip the first record of the input. But unless your input is already sorted, the one you skipped might be the next-lowest in the file.

I'd do this entirely differently. Let's assume that random access is possible on the input stream. I'd read the file once into a std::vector. You said you don't want to read it all that way due to memory issues. (It must be a really big file for that to be an issue.) But you could store an simple structure:

```
struct PowerIndex {
     size_t index;
     long power;
}
```

Just store the index (count) 0..n plus the power of the record you read.

Then sort THAT. You now can run through the vector, seek to the proper file location, read the record, write it, and you're done.

And it will be correct.

Of course, I still wonder whether random access is available on a generic `std::stream`.