# Generating file and .write is happening AFTER .call even though not written that way

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm trying to pass a java file via python and write the shell output into a log .txt file. This is working except that my manual breaks are being added to the end of the file. Any advice on why `.write` is happening after `subprocess.call`? I'm very new to Python. Thanks

**Code Snippet**

```
import subprocess

outfile = open('c:\\log2.txt', 'a')
outfile.write("\n\n")
outfile.write("-------------------------BEGIN NEW LOG--------------------------------------")
outfile.write("\n\n")
subprocess.call(['java.exe',
                 '-cp',
                 'c:\\dev\\dataloader\\dataloader-36.0.0-uber.jar',
                 '-Dsalesforce.config.dir=c:\\dev\\dataloader\\',
                 'com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner',
                 'process.name=csvCRExtract'],
                stdout=outfile)
outfile.close()
```

Comment: What happens if you call `close()` before you call `call()`?

Comment: you probably want to call `outfile.flush()` before the `subprocess.call()`. It may be a race condition for which process wins in emptying their output buffers.

Comment: @Kevin, that didn't work because I was closing the file (I assume). Here's the error: `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`

Comment: @Harvey that did work, but can you define "race" please? Will this not always return the same result? Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `output.flush()` before `subprocess.call()`.

`output` is using buffered i/o, meaning that it waits until a minimum amount of data has been written before actually writing the data to the operating system to avoid lots of slow system write calls. `flush` tells the buffer to send everything to the OS immediately. Your program was doing the following:

- writing your log header to the local buffer
- calling your java process which writes to its own buffer and then to the file when the process exits
- flushing your local buffer to the file when you `close` the file.

This answer has a picture and explains it a bit more:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1450563/47078