# Why does the spawn child process print to stdout only after execution with Python?

Tags: python, node.js, flush, spawn

I have created the following `node.js` code with the spawn child process that executes a `bash` code inside it:

```js
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn

const shellcode = `
file=$(mktemp)
cat > $file <<- "EOF"
echo "Hello World"
sleep 2
echo "Hello World"
sleep 2
echo "Hello World"
sleep 2
echo "Hello World"
EOF

bash $file
`

const child = spawn('/bin/bash', [ '-c',  shellcode ])

child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data.toString())
})
```

It works perfectly fine, it executes the `bash` inside the `shellcode` variable and it prints `Hello World` while the `node.js` code is running.

My problem starts with `Python`, I've created the following code:

```js
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn

const shellcode = `
file=$(mktemp)
cat > $file <<- "EOF"
import os

print('Hello World')
os.system("sleep 2")
print('Hello World')
os.system("sleep 2")
print('Hello World')
os.system("sleep 2")
print('Hello World')
EOF

python3 $file
`

const child = spawn('/bin/bash', [ '-c',  shellcode ])

child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data.toString())
})
```

However, this code doesn't execute as a `spawn` code. It waits for the process to finish to print the results to stdout. I've also tested the same logic with a node.js code inside the `shellcode` variable and it works fine just like bash. What am I getting wrong? I'm not sure if it's a `Python` issue or if it's a `node.js` issue. Why is the `Python` code not behaving as a spawn (it's waiting for the process to finish to print its output)?

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is that stdout uses [buffered I/o](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450551/buffered-vs-unbuffered-io).  SUGGESTION: Add either/both a final newline (`\n`) and/or an explicit [flush](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30845184/421195)

Comment: try using the options `{stdio:'inherit',env:process.env,cwd:undefined,shell:true}` as a third argument in the `spawn` command

Comment: I've tried adding `\n`, an explicit flush with `stdbuf -oL python3 $file` and `stdio:'inherit',env:process.env,cwd:undefined,shell:true}` as a third argument in the `spawn` command as said in the suggestions but none of them worked. The `spawn` is still behaving as an `exec` command when I'm executing `Python`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python buffers its output by default.

Run `python -u ...` or set the `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` environment variable to `1`.

As an aside, though, there's no reason to use `bash` here at all – Python can happily read code from stdin and execute it without a temporary file:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn

const shellcode = `
import os, time

print('Hello 1')
time.sleep(2)
print('Hello 2')
time.sleep(2)
print('Hello 3')
time.sleep(2)
print('Hello 4')
`.trim();

const child = spawn('/usr/bin/python3', ['-u', '-'], {stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', 'inherit']});
child.stdin.write(shellcode);
child.stdin.end();
child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(new Date(), data.toString());
});
```

prints out (at the time of writing):

```
2022-01-19T13:18:16.084Z Hello 1

2022-01-19T13:18:18.088Z Hello 2

2022-01-19T13:18:20.091Z Hello 3

2022-01-19T13:18:22.093Z Hello 4
```