# Extract stdout from long-running process

Tags: python, subprocess, python-asyncio

*Disclaimer: I have seen many similar questions, but either they do not use `asyncio`, or they don't seem to do exactly what I do.*

I am trying to get the output of a long-running command (it's actually a server that logs out to stdout) with the following:

```py
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(
        "my_long_running_command",
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        limit=10
    )

    stdout = ""
    try:
        stdout, stderr = await asyncio.wait_for(proc.communicate(), 2.0)
    except asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError:
        pass
    print(stdout)
```

But I don't get anything. If I use `ls` instead of `my_long_running_command`, it works. The only difference I see is that `ls` returns, and not my command.

I am using `wait_for` because [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#asyncio.subprocess.Process) says:

> the communicate() and wait() methods don’t have a timeout parameter: use the wait_for() function;

I tried with `limit=10`, hoping it would help with the buffering, and without it. It seems to have no effect at all.

Though I don't really understand how they differ, I tried both `asyncio.create_subprocess_shell` and `asyncio.create_subprocess_exec` without success.

Is there a way to extract stdout from the process before it returns?

Comment: Maybe the buffering could be a problem? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606795/catching-stdout-in-realtime-from-subprocess

Comment: Hmm not sure what you suggest, those seem to be using Popen and not asyncio...

Comment: The I/O buffering is general concept. It doesn't matter if you open the process via Popen or via asyncio: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450551/buffered-vs-unbuffered-io

Comment: Oh, right. So I tried to set the `limit` argument to a small number (10), but it did not seem to help :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `await proc.stdout.readline()` for reading from standard output in realtime. For example:

```py
import asyncio

async def main():
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        "top",                        # <--- some long running task
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
    )

    line = await proc.stdout.readline()
    while line:
        print(line.decode())
        line = await proc.stdout.readline()


asyncio.run(main())
```

---

EDIT: Using `await proc.stdout.read()`:

```py
import asyncio

async def main():
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        "watch", "-n", "2", "ls", "-alF", "/",
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
    )

    char = await proc.stdout.read(1)
    while char:
        print(char.decode(), end='')
        char = await proc.stdout.read(1)


asyncio.run(main())
```

---

EDIT 2: When two above solutions don't work, try to turn-off the buffering in terminal:

```
stdbuf -o0 <your command here>
```

Also, running this Python script without buffering. (for example, using the `-u` python command line flag)

Comment: Interestingly, it works with top, but not with my binary... though if I comment out `stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,`, then my program prints output on stdout... My binary being a static executable, `mavsdk_server_musl_x86_64` from https://github.com/mavlink/MAVSDK/releases/tag/v1.4.12. Could it be doing something weird with stdout? Not sure what to look for :/

Comment: @JonasVautherin Maybe the program doesn't send newlines (`\n`). I've updated my answer, where I read the stdout one byt at the time.

Comment: Works for watch, not for `mavsdk_server` :-/. It's weird because really it starts by sending a few lines to stdout (with version number, etc), so there must be something to read.

Comment: @JonasVautherin I'm now just guessing, it might be something with buffering. Try to add `stdbuf -o0` before the command. Source: https://www.baeldung.com/linux/stdbuf-pipe-turn-off-buffer . And when you run this python script, try to turn Python buffering off too (`-u` switch) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering

Comment: More than happy to get your guesses, because I'm out of ideas :D. Let me try this!

Comment: It works with `stdbuf -o0`!!!!! I'm using your `readline()` example above now, with `stdbuf -o0`.

Comment: (please just add `stdbuf` to your answer and I'll mark it as solved ;) )